# Grouping and Multiindexing a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multi-index, pandas-groupby

Suppose I have a dataframe as follows

```
In [6]: df.head()
Out[6]: 
     regiment company      name  preTestScore  postTestScore
0  Nighthawks     1st    Miller             4             25
1  Nighthawks     1st  Jacobson            24             94
2  Nighthawks     2nd       Ali            31             57
3  Nighthawks     2nd    Milner             2             62
4    Dragoons     1st     Cooze             3             70
```

I have a dictionary as follows:

`army = {'Majors' : 'Nighthawks', 'Captains' : 'Dragoons'}`

and I want that it and should have a multi-index in the shape of ["army","company"] only.

How will I proceed?

Comment: I believe it is dupe, so only comment - use `df = df.set_index(["regiment","company"])`

Comment: check also [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)

Comment: @jezrael yeah thanks, I edited my ques, This is what I intended to ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

You can use `map` to find values in a dictionary (using dictionary comprehension to swap key/value pairs since they are backwards):

```
army = {'Majors': 'Nighthawks', 'Captains': 'Dragoons'}

df.assign(army=df.regiment.map({k:v for v, k in army.items()})).set_index(['army', 'company'], drop=True)
                    regiment      name  preTestScore  postTestScore
army     company                                                   
Majors   1st      Nighthawks    Miller             4             25
         1st      Nighthawks  Jacobson            24             94
         2nd      Nighthawks       Ali            31             57
         2nd      Nighthawks    Milner             2             62
Captains 1st        Dragoons     Cooze             3             70
```